# Magento2.1 Unable to load phtml file in CMS

Tags: magento-2.1

Wondering if you can help here.
I know how to load the standard login.phtml so that a frontend user can login/register to their accounts.

```
{{block template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml"}}
{{block template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml"}}
```

However, I am using a plugin that allows vendors to login, and would like to access that phtml on the CMS.  I tried using the following code that I derived from the template hints.

```
{{block class ="Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Vendor\Form\Login" template="Ced_CsMarketplace::customer/form/login.phtml"}}
```

[image: Template Hints]

However, nothing loads in its place. I am able to see that `customer/form/login.phtml` file on the server directory structure, no issue, and it's loading fine on the standard(but ugly) login page. Is it possible that I'm missing something?
[image: View of HTML Widget]

How can I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

This one was tricky to solve as the login form required additional parameters:

```
{{block class="Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Vendor\Form\Login" name="vendor_form_login" template="Ced_CsMarketplace::customer/form/login.phtml" cacheable="false"}}
```

Just wondering how I could troubleshoot something like this in the future?

I'd be happy to hear your recommendations.

Comment: {{block type="your/block" class="Ced\CsMarketplace\Block\Vendor\Form\Login" name="vendor_form_login" template="Ced_CsMarketplace::customer/form/login.phtml" cacheable="false"}}